# sitefinity form populate dropdownlist from API

Tags: sitefinity

I would like to create a form and add a dropdown list widget that will pull its choices from an API. I don't see any setting for that where would I call the API? what I was able to find is from 2014 so I think its outdated.

https://www.progress.com/blogs/sitefinity-custom-form-widget-with-dependent-dropdowns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's cake... just use a regular input, then on the page use a Javascript widget and wire it up into a dropdown.

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/remotedatasource

Use whatever JS component you want

Just a note though, give your input a cssclass name that will let you easily find it with the javascript.

I have a post on this https://www.sitefinitysteve.com/blog/binding-sitefinity-form-field-to-remote-data

Comment: Thanks @steve-mcniven-scott what setting do you use for the JS widget?  `where to include in HTML ?`

Comment: 99.9% of the time, bottom